# Delete / update "please consider adding a comment" message when downvoting questions

Tags: feature-request, comments, downvotes, notifications

When downvoting a (recent?) question, a prompt appears stating:

> Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

I feel like this should either:

1. Take into account whether you already upvoted another comment that already points out what is wrong with the post / how it can be improved, so that it wouldn't show if I had already upvoted another comment to that question, especially since adding another constructive comment would just make the comment section cluttered and unnecessarily messy.
2. Not be shown at all, because of what Oleg pointed out in the comments:

   > Nothing good comes from this guidance as users tend to lash out on downvoters who dare to try to help them out along the way

Comment: I think we should just remove it entirely.

Comment: Worse, they lash out at the commenters. I've gotten some pretty good shellackings from misguided folks after trying to explain what I believed got their precious and perfect post a downvote.

Comment: Sidenote: If you're going to comment and downvote, comment first. No point to downvoting, getting part-way through the explanation and wasting the effort because the asker deletes the post rather than making what could have been a trivial fix.

Comment: this looks related: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/839601)

Answer (score 31):

Can we just get rid of that messaging? The community has moved past this guidance and opted not to become pin cushions for someone who gets downvoted.

Comment: It does say "Please consider"...feedback *can* be helpful, and in the majority of cases, it's well-received.  Unfortunately, it's the few bad apples who respond poorly that have ruined it for everyone else.

Comment: Feedback can, indeed, be helpful, and there shouldn't be any discouragement to users who want to provide it, but it shouldn't be in any way connected to votes, and the message is doing a disservice by implying that there should be a relationship.

Comment: I think that explaining a downvote helps a lot when you try to improve your participation in this community, and also helps other people in finding these explanations in a natural way. If some users lash out against downvoters, maybe those are users we simply don't want here and the solution goes through getting rid of them. As we say in Spain, this makes *the righteous pay for the sinners*.

Comment: Do you feel that explaining an upvote also helps a lot, @S.Dre? How do you know what, specifically, to keep doing, unless someone explains their upvote? The point is that feedback is useful in general. However, votes are not meant to be feedback to the poster (although they are feedback to others, in that they rank the accuracy, usefulness, and interestingness of the post); if someone wants to leave feedback for the author of a post, they can and will post a comment. Upvotes and downvotes *can* be interpreted as feedback by the author, but only in a limited/obvious sense—see the tooltip.

Comment: In general, an upvote is issued when the question is good as it is. I think you can basically take from them that it is useful etc. and no critical changes are needed. Not all downvotes need an explanation though, but it is fairly useful in a lot of cases. Specially when there is something wrong with it aside from not being useful in the platform.

Comment: In fact, I have indeed seen people commenting on an upvote when they are surprised by a nice behaviour or code practice etc. enough to comment on it. In the case of downvotes, if the question is obviously horrendous, then I wouldn't bother commenting on it either.

Comment: This feels like the entirely wrong guidance to me. The very largest bulk of my comments-on-downvoted-content do *not* result in recipients lashing out or making me a pin cushion; this narrative feels to me as seriously overblown. Rather, knowing that a good deal of downvotes-without-suggestions are because I am seen as a potentially vile and vengeful being is disheartening. This kind of guidance that harms those trying to improve while protecting the actually harmful actors feels extremely toxic. When even guidance to *consider* a comment is too much, something is very, very wrong...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi:  [I'm laconically rephrasing what was already said about comments on downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/1079354), with a lot more terseness.

Comment: @Makoto I'm well aware that comments can be received negatively, but I think there's an important difference between comments thus being *not required* versus *not recommended*. *Considering* to add a comment still leaves room to decide against it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi:  The system is making a suggestion to us that the community is actively discouraging.  That's really the long and the short of it, and I believe that the system needs to get on the same page with the community here. Otherwise, you'll get someone just commenting with whatever they can get out of slamming their palm on the keyboard to pacify this message.

Comment: @Makoto "that the community is actively discouraging" I disagree with that assessment. "you don't have to" and "you should not" are completely different things. As far as I can tell, *expecting* a comment is discouraged but not *leaving* a comment. "you'll get someone just commenting with whatever they can get out of slamming their palm on the keyboard to pacify this message." I also disagree with that. It's no problem at all to mentally dismiss the message, especially if one considers to leave a comment and still decides against it.

Comment: There are certainly dozens of meta posts where users falsely believed that popup was telling them commenting was necessary after downvoting, and using that as a basis for complaining about people not following it.

Comment: As I've said before, the system should make it **impossible** to comment on a post that you've downvoted, and vice versa. IMHO, that would eliminate most angry reprisals, revenge downvotes, etc.

Comment: @Gimby I do appreciate the edit but the tone of my response there is that people still *presume* they're being downvoted, even though we don't downvote people - we downvote content.  Someone lashing out at us is seldom because they thought their question was downvotable - they've more than likely taken it as an attack on their own character.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi 100% agreed. Commenting something along the lines of `Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and <lengthy, specific description of how to improve the post>` has become my primary way of interacting with the site. On a day that I decide to check in, I might do this dozens of times and get an upset OP *maybe* once. I shrug it off because I know that I am the established community member upholding community norms. I get thankful feedback **much** more often. Also, from personal experience it feels **vastly** worse to be downvoted without feedback, than with.

Comment: @KevinB there are many, many places where I would blame the site UI for poor communication with users. Users seeing `Please consider` and understanding `Thou shalt` is absolutely **not** one of them. That's 100% on the users in question. That said, I strongly believe that comments on downvotes *should* happen more often, which is why I personally comment on all my downvotes (and sometimes even hold back the downvote) and put considerable effort into them. I strongly believe that *telling people specifically how to behave better, correlates with them eventually actually behaving better*.

Comment: @Makoto "Someone lashing out at us is seldom because they thought their question was downvotable - they've more than likely taken it as an attack on their own character." What I don't understand is how so many people apparently take it for granted that *taking the opportunity to explain the problem with the question* somehow makes it **more** likely that the downvote will be taken as a personal attack. I've lost count of the times I've gotten frustrated - across the entire Internet - because I *couldn't get anyone to explain* the negative feedback I was receiving.

Comment: It seems like people keep complaining about the duplicate meta posts asking why downvotes don't require an explanatory comment. What they seem to be missing is that *people actively want the feedback*. Those posts are being made by people who want the feedback, *because* they want the feedback, and it feels **devastatingly awful** not to get it and just see a negative number next to your content. Seriously, the emotion is so strong that it's a bit hard for me to type this all out. Also: the reasoning in the top answer for the canonical is IMO deeply flawed, and I wish I could comment there.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel;  If people want the feedback, petition the *system* to express it on our behalf, not *us*.  If *we* act as stop-gaps to the system, then we will never achieve consistent and useful feedback to users in this situation which would entirely defeat the purpose you're so desperately yearning for.

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting. Some kind of AI to make the kind of comments I currently do?